# character encoding in java

Tags: java, io

I have tried the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String s = "NETWORK";
    try (
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:/endian.txt");
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF_16BE");) {
        osw.write(s);
        osw.flush();

    }
}
```

after running, I get a file that contains the following chain: N E T W O R K; the size of the resulting file is 14 bytes (7 characters * 2 bytes). notice the spaces between characters of the chain.
when I change the encoding with: UTF_16LE, I get a file size of 14 bytes, which contains the following string: NETWORK. no spaces between characters !!. I expect a string as follows: N E T W O R K. i used notepad to open the file.
Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Where is the difference between the two attempts? I see you use UTF_16LE for both?

Comment: what happens if you replace `"UTF_16LE"` to `"UTF_8"` ??

Comment: in which encoding does notepad open the file? does it match the one you use?

Comment: I got your code and it is working as expected. When I use charset of UTF_16LE, it is generating N E T W O R K with file size 14 KB. When I don't use anything, as expected, the string is NETWORK, file size 7 KB. What is your issue?

Comment: Use a hex editor, not a text editor, to look at the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary representation of the "NETWORK" string using:

- **UTF_16BE** is:

  00 4E 00 45 00 54 00 57 00 4F 00 52 00 4B (Notepad: `N E T W O R K`)
- **UTF_16LE** is:

  4E 00 45 00 54 00 57 00 4F 00 52 00 4B 00 (Notepad: `NETWORK`)

The reason for behaviour that you are describing is because Notepad recognizes **UTF_16BE** representation of the "NETWORK" string as `ANSI` and **UTF_16LE** representation of "NETWORK" string as `UNICODE`.

As already suggested it would be better to use a [hex editor](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to look at the binary representation of produced files in order to see exactly what gets written.

Comment: You probably mean "UTF_16LE representation of "NETWORK" string as UNICODE"

Comment: Thank you.. That's what I meant.

Comment: indeed, when I use a hex editor, I got the expected result. thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

Don't use notepad to open the file. It does a terrible job of detecting encoding. Use a better tool in which you can specify the encoding, e.g. NotePad++ or a hex editor.

Comment: NotePad++ gives the same result